# Mobile Application Xamarin.Form, what is the use of TabLayoutResource and ToolbarResource

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am new using Xamarin and I am using VS2019, I created a new project using Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms).

The MainActivity class is defined as MainLauncher and I understand it.

That class also have two lines of code within the OnCreate method

*TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;*

*ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;*

Tabbar and Toolbar are defined within the Resource.designer and the views are placed within the Layout folder.

Then the App is loaded, the MainPage is assigned and loaded too. The Views within the Views folder are loaded

And the application is building and showing fine.

I understand (at least that is what I think) the Xamarin application cycle, but what I do not understand is the use of those two lines of code.

*TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;*

*ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;*

If I comment or delete those lines, the application still working fine.

**What is the purpose of those lines?**

Answer (score 4):

> What is the purpose of those lines?

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

These two lines in Xmarin.Forms Android used to set the layout resource. To specify the toolbar and tabs layout in Resource/layout folder so Xamarin.Forms knows how to reference them. 
[image]

> If I comment or delete those lines, the application still working fine.

When you comment or delete, the application works well, but it would lose the default layout.

I use `toolbaritem` for reference.

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Example Item"
         IconImageSource="monkeyicon.png"
         Order="Primary"
         Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

**The original layout:**

[image]

**When I comment it, the layout would be below.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You use those lines to setup the style of the tabbar and toolbar on Android. Many of those setups where missing in the earlier versions of Xamarin.Forms, so those things are much less needed now, but I think they still offer a more wide level of customization.